# Custom component with NgModel throws: No provider for CustomInputComponent

Tags: angular

I've just started learning Angular 2 and now I'm trying to use a Custom Component with NgModel. I have created a `select` component that I reuse in other components and now I need to pass it the selected value.

To do it I have copied this working example from [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/nqKUSPWb6w5QXr8a0wEu/?show=preview).

But when I try to use it, I get the message:

```
No provider for CustomInputComponent
```

This is the custom component typescript:

```
import { Component, Inject, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { ILaw } from '../../interfaces/law.interface';

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: 'law',
    templateUrl: './law.component.html',
    providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class LawComponent {
    public laws: ILaw[];
    public selectedLaw: number;

    @Output()
    notifyParent: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor(private http: Http,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {

        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Law').subscribe(result => {
            this.laws = result.json() as ILaw[];
            console.log(this.laws);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    lawChanges() {
        console.log("selected law: " + this.selectedLaw);
        this.notifyParent.emit(this.selectedLaw);
    }
}

export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    //The internal data model
    private innerValue: any = '';

    //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
    //by the Control Value Accessor
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

    //get accessor
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    //Set touched on blur
    onBlur() {
        this.onTouchedCallback();
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }
}
```

And its html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="lawChanges()">
    <option></option>
    <option *ngFor="let law of laws" [value]="law.lawId">{{law.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And here is where I use the `law` component:

```
<law (notifyParent)="getNotification($event, rowIndex)" [(ngModel)]="productionorder.lawId"></law>
```

I've been searching but I haven't found anything useful and this seems to be not very easy to do it (or unless I don't understand how to do it because the samples I have found are very complicated).

I've been using the `law` component without any problem in other components but now I need to pass it the selected value in a new one. It is also registered in `app.module.shared.ts`.

Why is it not working?

Comment: i hope you registered this component in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you forgot to anotate your `CustomInputComponent` with `@Component` decorator